# Click a span element with AutoIt

Tags: autoit

I would like to learn how to click on a span element with AutoIt. Here is the code for the span element.

```
<span class="ng-binding">Reports</span>
```

This is what the span looks like as a button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your element, you can try with [this function](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/98111-_iegetobjbyclass/?do=findComment&comment=705819):

```
_IEGetObjByClass($oIE, 'ng-binding')
```